# find highest of each type from Map in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, dictionary

I am creating the ArrayList of Object, to insert information I use different constructors in that class but I have one type variable that I update with every constructor call. here is what i am doing

```
public class eProperty {
    public String type = null;
    public int marks;
    public int code;
    public String category
    public String student_name = null;
    public String employee_name = null;
    public String o_name = null;

    public eProperty(String type, String student_name, int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
        this.type = type;
        this.student_name = student_marks;
    }

    public eProperty(String type, String employee_name, int makrs, String category) {
        this.marks = marks;
        this.type = type;
        this.employee_name = employee_name;
        this.category = category;
    }
    public eProperty(String type, int code, int makrs, String o_name) {
        this.marks = marks;
        this.type = type;
        this.mnc = code;
        this.o_name = o_name;
    }
}
```

I populate arraylist like this,

```
ArrayList<eProperty> allData;
eProperty data;

if(type.equals("Student")) {
   data = new eProperty(type, "John", 45)
   allData.add(data)
}
if(type.equals("Employee")){
 data = new eProperty(type, "Vicky", 86, "Developer")
 allData.add(data)
} ... other cases also handled like this
```

Now I want to retrive highest marks for each type and I am stuck here, any help

Thanks

Comment: do a loop on your arrayList, make variables(maxStu, max...), check type, compare, assign value... where are you stuck?

Comment: but i wanted to avoid loops and all, is not there any cleaner way, I tried to do using Map too but not very good

Comment: If you use Java 8, you can use streams for this. Otherwise, you have to use a loop.

Comment: why you want to avoid looping? loop through the list, and find the max, `O(n)`. you can use TreeSet for different types, it adds unnecessary overheads, it turns `O(n) -> O(nlogn)` ... again, why don't you want to use loop?

Comment: I just wanted to find a way by using Dictionary or some other trick that is it...to increase my scope

Comment: Use a self-ordering data structure and override your `compareTo()` method for your `eProperty` to compare `marks` from the two objects being compared. This will make insertions more expensive, order depending on structure chosen, but will make finding maximum values O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using loop (sorry for that...) and `Predicate` from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)

```
public static int getHighestMarkByType(ArrayList<eProperty> allData, String type) {

    Predicate predicate = new Predicate() {
        public boolean evaluate(Object data) {
            if ((eProperty) data).getType().equals(type)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    ArrayList<eProperty> filteredData = (ArrayList<eProperty>) CollectionUtils.select(allData,predicate);

    int maxMarks = 0;

    for (eProperty data : filteredData) {
        if (data.getMarks() > maxMark) {
            maxMarks = data.getMark();
        }
    }

    return maxMarks;
}
```